# Buscar url y reemplazar por otra en txt con python

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo .txt que contiene varias urls, entre todas quiero buscar las que terminan con extensión zip y rar, luego cambiarle el dominio/ip por otro y por último guardar en el mismo archivo.

Ejemplo de file.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur http://url.com/file.zip
Curabitur sit amet semper erat http://www.gogle.com/
Cras viverra neque et libero eleifend http://158.989.87.7/file.rar
http://url.com/image.jpg
```

Output de file.txt

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur http://miserver.com/file.zip
Curabitur sit amet semper erat http://www.gogle.com/
Cras viverra neque et libero eleifend http://miserver.com/file.rar
http://url.com/image.jpg
```

Sé que con regex lo puedo buscar, pero acudo aquí porque no se como empezar y tampoco he encontrado algo tan específico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente no soy un experto en expresiones regulares, pero esto debería funcionar.

```
lista = [
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur http://url.com/file.zip',
'Curabitur sit amet semper erat http://www.gogle.com/',
'Cras viverra neque et libero eleifend http://158.989.87.7/file.rar',
'http://url.com/image.jpg'
]

import re

patron = r'\/\/([^\/]+)\/.+\.(rar|zip)'

for linea in lista:
  m = re.search(patron, linea)
  if m:
    linea = linea.replace(m.group(1), "miserver.com")

  print(linea)
```

El funcionamiento es sencillo,recorremos la lista y a cada línea le aplicamos el patrón `regex` que tiene un grupo a capturar que coincidiría justamente con el dominio. Si hay coincidencia simplemente reemplazamos este texto por el del nuevo dominio.

En cuanto al patrón:

- Debe coincidir con `\/\/` Las dos barras `//` y luego ...
- `([^\/]+)` capturamos cualquier caracter menos la `/` hasta ...
- `\/` la siguiente barra y que además coincida con ...
- `.+\.(rar|zip)` cualquier caracter, un punto y las extensiones menciondas

Comment: Gracias Patricio. El código funciona a la perfección. Como hago lo mismo para tomar de un txt y guardarlo? He intentado así, pero me devuelve `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Te dejo link para que mires el código > https://shar.es/ano5Sl

Comment: @tomillo, acá te dejo una forma en que puedes hacerlo: https://repl.it/@pmoracho/Test

Comment: Excelente Patricio. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!